# small sample (1 point) MLE estimation

Tags: probability, statistics, regression

I'm trying to estimate $m$ in $y = mx+e$ from a single $(x,y)$ observation.

$m,x,e$ are all $N(0,1)$ and independent.

If I do a Monte-Carlo estimation on say $(1,3)$ I get about $1.5$. This seems about right.

What I'm struggling to do is estimate the MLE of $m$ analytically.

(I'm only interested in the single point case)

Comment: it would seem that  y/2x is the answer, but I cannot derive this.

Comment: Are you sure you want *all* the parameters to be random? Or only $\epsilon$ as in simple linear regression?

Comment: yes.  But I would be interested in what you would do if m was not random.  To estimate it you would surely need an assumption about its distribution ?

Comment: @I've provided an answer for the "all random" situation. The case where $m$ is not random is not very hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't observed $\epsilon$ or $m$, you have the following joint distribution of $m$ and $\epsilon$:

$$f(m,\epsilon) = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2+m^2}{2}}$$

However, you've also observed $x,y$ so we know that $m,\epsilon$ took values such that the linear relationship between $y,x$ holds.

To get a likelihood function for $m$, lets consider $m=k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$:

For the equation to hold between $x,y$ $m=k$ requires:

$$\epsilon = y-kx$$

Therefore, the likelihood of $m$ depends on both how unlikely it is that $m=k$ and that $$\epsilon = y-kx$$ so we get the following likelihood function for $m$:

$$L(m|x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{(y-mx)^2+m^2}{2}}$$

From the basic properties of $e^{-u^2}$, we know $L(m|x,y)$ will be maximized when $(y-mx)^2+m^2$ is minimized. Using some basic calculus:

$$\frac{d}{dm} (y-mx)^2+m^2 = 2(mx^2+m-xy)$$

Since $(y-mx)^2+m^2$ is convex, we know that if we find the point where the its derivative is $0$, then we have found the global minimum:

$$2(mx^2+m-xy) = 0 \implies m = \frac{xy}{x^2+1}$$

Therefore, this is your MLE. I.e.,

$$\hat{m} = \frac{xy}{x^2+1}$$

For example, in your Monte Carlo study of $(1,3)$ we would estimate that $m=\frac{1(3)}{1^2+1} = \frac32$, which is in agreement with your results.

Comment: That's great, thanks.   Now I see why I couldn't get my Likelihood function to work (which matches yours) -- I was confusing Expectation with ML.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1202733 no problem. Glad this clarified things. Its a subtle point with ML on random parameters.